# Spring Hibernate MySQL- 50k insert taking 20minutes

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, batch-processing

I have been working on a project using the latest appfuse as a base.. I have extended a lot of the models particularly the User to accommodate some of the things I am doing, one of them is adding a few Lists to the user that have larger lists attached to them, here is an example:
User -> LeadLists (maybe 100 or so of these) -> Leads (Upwards of 50k) 
And that is where my problems start. I have a process working that the user uploads a CSV I parse that into Lead objects and add them to the list then to the user then save the user and let cascade save do its work. However once save fires it takes 20 minutes or more for it to finish and usually with a permGen memory error...
Problem #2 is once they are actually in the DB I have not been able to display them at all without getting another permGen out of memory error.

Can anyone please offer some insight into what I may be doing wrong? I have enabled the hibernate batch size and set it to 50, what else can I do to get this ridiculous insert time down?

Comment: Are you eagerly loading everything all the elements in your list?

Comment: Some nice comment can be found in @bellabax reply, but did you considered the fact that you may have been ended in a swapping problem? Memory runs out of space, thus keep being moved to disk and viceversa, slowing down drastically time of execution..

Comment: @LGM: you can overpower machine where application is running on, but is not a final solution; what happens if 50K became 100K? You give more vitamine to your PC? Every hardware upgrade requires money for our customers or company. IMO is better build up a robust batch programming and use hardware upgrade only if absolutely necessary

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis I am using Eager loading

Comment: Dustin, as bellabax suggests, if you can work through the complex Spring-batch setup it may be your best bet. I recently did a small sample tutorial project of inserting .cvs data into a MySQL, but it was much simpler than what you are doing. I used Spring-batch 2.2.0 and Hibernate 4, and set the Hibernate and Spring batch size settings at 100. I used Spring-batch for the processing, but the Hibernate Session-factory. With no refresh, write() coding, or batch clearing, I was able to insert 400,000 records in about 10 minutes, with no cache issues. If interested, I can provide some code.

Comment: @wSchmidt I would love to see some code, it looks like Spring Batch is the way I have to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you write your code using Hibernate batch processing best pratice?
If not, check this [link](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/batch.html).
If yes and you are trying to write a single User+LeadLists(100)+Leads(50k) in a single shot (are 50K items!!! That's no peanuts!) you have this choices:

1. Move all to flat JDBC (ORM sometimes are not the best choice for batch programming) can be a good solution, but required you to rewrite some parts of code probably,
2. Move to StatelessSession (just to give it a chance),but I think PermGen error is around the corner,
3. Increase PermGen space - sized on some statistics about objects dimension, for example - can resolve PermGen problem but not slow issue
4. Drastic: Move to Spring-batch, framework used to perform batch conversion of big amount of data. Probably you will reduce by a lot saving time, but for sure you will resolve PermGen space (the real problem, IMO. A slow program is better than one that crash and lose data)

My 2 cents

Comment: Thanks for your help. @bellabax Spring is handling the session and that stuff but I have tried to follow the steps on the link you posted. What I am trying to write is this: User+LeadList(1)+Leads(50k) I am using the generic .save() method, I might try writing my own and splitting the load into 1000's? I know Hibernate is batching because I can get it to error and it will show it coming from "BatchingBatch.performExecution". I will give your other suggestions a try starting with the statelessSession.

Comment: if I do try to use Spring-batch how do I keep my object relations? since the Leads object are the ones that need the batching

Comment: spring-batch is based on different concepts and need re-thinking about your batch steps (this is the reason why I defined it __drastic__)...